# How to check if auto renewal subscription have been made IOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I develop a multi platform app and this is the first time I use the apple in app purchase subscription. For now all the subscription process is all right but I would like to add a check function when the app is open. If the renew have been done so the Firebase Date will be update to the new end date to allow other platform to now it.

I have my function :

```
func userPrivilegeAllowed(){



    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser{
        // user is connect
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        ref.child("User_Subscribtion").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let expStringDate = value?["Expiry_Date"] as? String ?? "01/01/01"

            self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
            let expiryDate = self.dateFormatter.date(from: expStringDate) ?? self.dateFormatter.date(from: "01/01/1990")

            self.today.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
            self.today.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"

            var dayBeforeExpiry = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: self.curentDate, to: expiryDate!)

            if dayBeforeExpiry.year! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.month! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.day! <= 0{

                self.StartBtn.isHidden = true
                self.StopBtn.isHidden = true
                self.unpaidBtn.isHidden = false

            } else if dayBeforeExpiry.year! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.month! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.day! <= 7{
                self.unpaidBtn.isHidden = true
                self.WarningSubscription.isHidden = false
            } else if dayBeforeExpiry.year! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.month! == 0 && dayBeforeExpiry.day! == 1{
                //Add Check if Apple payement is OK or Not !

            }

        }

    }
}
```

How can I get the new end date to update or not the database and allow or not the user to use the app?

I now there is already some informations about this question in internet but I'm not really familiar with the IOS development and I need more help ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To keep the users subscription status up-to-date, you'll need to store the purchase receipt on your server and periodically refresh it with Apple to get the latest expiration date from the receipt file. You can just do the refresh as the renewal period approaches, or more frequently to catch cancellations/refunds.

With the code you shared, a user could change the system time on their phone and get access to your subscription forever. You should do the date check against the time on your server.

Here is a good blog post that explains the server side in more detail: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f). You can also check out [their service](https://www.revenuecat.com/) that manages all of this for you. (Disclaimer: I work there)

Comment: thanks for information, I never use the in app subscription so I'll try to follow the process given by revenueCat thanks !